# Telerik object data source - access complex list items

Tags: telerik-reporting

**How to access fields from a complex list structure?**

I have custom Object data source that works.  But I cant access the embedded list.

I can access the values main structure.  `=Fields.ObjectId`  works as expected.

But how do i access a specific row the sublist?

I have tried `=fields.sublist[int].value` and got a run time error.

> " The expression contains object 1 that is not defined in the current
>   context."

**psuedoCode**  of what im attempting

> =Fields.BODPropValList.[PropertyName("XYZ")].Value

I cant find any docu explaining how to do this.

**EDIT:** 
I dont want to bind it to a table since I need to access a single field from single sub row.

**The data access object**

```
  [DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Select)]
   public List<BODRow> GetBODRowData(string dirId)        {
        .. code retrieves the list and delivers it..  
        return bodRowList;
    }
}

public class BODRow   {
    public string ObjectId { get ;set; } }
    public string DirId { get ; set; } }
    public string ViewDirId { get; set; }
    public  List<BODPropVal>  BODPropValList { get; set; }
    }
}

public class BODPropVal {

    public virtual string PropertyName { get; set; }
    public virtual string Value { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found a solution.
You can call static method you add to the reports partial class section.
Then in expression editor it can be called

`=Namespace.Report.StaticMethod()`

you can even pass parameters into the call.
If you declare the static routine with attribute   `[DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Select)]`
it will appear in a special list of methods under Object Data sources

```
namespace MyNameSpace.MyTelerikReportLibrary
{
[DataObject]
public class ReportDataSource {

[DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Select)]
    public static string GetBodDataLabel(string propName, string lang)        {
        return "code that returns your text"
    }
{
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you show the example of the static method you created for this?

Answer (score 0):

Found this on Telerik's forum. Looks like you need to add initialization of `List<BODPropVal>` in a default constructor for `BODRow`.

http://www.telerik.com/forums/bind-data-to-table-form-nested-objects-nested-list

Comment: thx for trying CamperWill.  I want to address the subslist as using a field expression. There is not table to  bind to and the data delivered has main record and sublist set.